# VMware snapshot + An error occurred while saving the snapshot msg.snap-hot error

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, snapshot

I am using VMware version 5.5 (that manage 57 different VM Linux machines –red-hat version 6 until 7 )
In the VSphere Client (tasks and event), I saw the following error: (on Linux machine name – Korfo_prod43 )

```
An error occurred while saving the snapshot msg.snap-hot error –Q- UIESCINGERROR
```

And when I try to log via SSH to the Linux machine, I notice that Linux machine is Hung (freeze state), so only reboot was needed to start up again the machine

In order to find a resolution for the snapshot problem,

I find the following resolution but not sure if this resolution is completely fit for my problem?

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2116120

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this issue in the past. Updating to the patches recommended in the KB fixed the issue.

An alternative workaround, which I used until I was able to patch, is to edit `/etc/vmware-tools/tools.conf`, and add these lines:

```
[vmbackup]
enableSyncDriver = false
```

This will cause the snapshot to only run a sync operation before the snapshot, and to not run a quiesce on the filesystem.

---

Reference: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1257523

Answer (score 0):

May be. Updated VmWare tools - is good practice. Notice, what VmWare recommends use open vm tools from distro. One more check free space on you storage - may be with snapshot or ram image it's exceeded. Check VM from client or cli for lost snapshots, make consolidation, if needed. Check datastore for garbage files